# Outlook 2010 hanging, 50GB PST file

Tags: exchange, outlook

One of my customers Outlook keeps hanging he is blaming our exchange server but i strongly suspect it is related to a 30GB and 20GB archive data pst files he has attached.

We have hundreds of other customers and no one else complains so i dont believe its the exchange server.

PST scanfix tool reported corruptions on these and apparently were fixed.

Customer is not prepared to archive off the messages with larger attatchments to his file system so we can merge remaining mail to his ost exchange mailbox (his inbox limit is 25GB).

He now wants exchange removed and going back to POP3 but i strongly suspect the hanging problem will remain.

Couple of questions:

If Microsoft consider 5GB a large pst size what is their definition of 50GB of pst files?

What is the actual limit of pst files that outlook can handle but remain stable?

Why does pst corruption occur?

What else can be done to stop outlook crashing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If Microsoft consider 5GB a large pst size what is their definition of 50GB of pst files?

Likely among the line of "Idiotic".

> What is the actual limit of pst files that outlook can handle but remain stable?

You will find that depending a lot on Hardware, too. Larger than 5gb lower than 50gb These days.

> Why does pst corruption occur?

Memory flipping for example.

> What else can be done to stop outlook crashing?

Update to 2013 (likely better in halding larger Areas), put in a 64gb RAM Setup on a SSD, nothing.

At the end, 50gb is too large. Point. If the c ustomer wants to go bac kto POP3, have him do so, then sort out the mess himself ;)

Comment: +1 50GB is absolutely beyond reasonable. Exchange supports clients pulling e-mail via POP3, switch him over and let the problems continue...